# File.Copy not overwriting image

Tags: c#, copy

I'm trying to copy an image from one folder and copy to another folder to overwrite, but it doesn't work. If the file I want to overwrite isn't there it will create a new copy, but if it exists it doesn't overwrite it.

```
            int itemIndex = leftImage.SelectedIndex;
            FileInfo fi = ImageList[itemIndex].fileInfo;
            File.Copy(fi.FullName, $"out/leftImage{fi.Extension}", overwrite: true);

            Console.WriteLine($"filePath: {fi.FullName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"fileOutput: {$"out/leftImage{fi.Extension}"}");
```

Example console output:

```
filePath: E:\GIT\smashHelper\Smash Helper\Smash Helper\bin\Debug\images\23.png
fileOutput: out/leftImage.png
```

The file locations are both correct for where I want to get the image and where i want to put it. They also both have the same file extensions

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `File.Copy` however there is with your assumptions. Firstly, we dont use forward slashes for a directory path. Secondly, the image is likely not being output where you think. Use a full path instead to prove this for your self

Comment: Changing it to use the full directory results in the same behavior. It will copy the file to the proper location when no file there already exists, but it won't if the file exists.
`File.Copy(fi.FullName, $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\out\\leftImage{fi.Extension}", true);`
Results in the path
`fileOutput: E:\GIT\smashHelper\Smash Helper\Smash Helper\bin\Debug\out\leftImage.png`
And behaves the same as before

Comment: I would suggest taking this back to absolute basics, Create a little app, with just a `File.Copy(@"D:\Test.data",@"D:\Test2.data",true);` and see if you are getting the results you expect, when you get that working, then expand it to your bigger app

Comment: Do you get an exception?  If so, you should post it here verbatim.

Comment: @TheGeneral .Net (and Windows in general in most cases) is happy with both forward and backward slashes. Using forward slashes in the paths help if you have .Net core code running in non-Windows...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov happy to be corrected, and you are indeed right. I guess I have slash OCD

Comment: Collin Anderson - While I understand that you *do* use `overwrite:true` there is really no way to help you more that "this is how it should be" (essentially why I used duplicate so future users can see correct code/explanation). You are welcome to do more investigation and [edit] question with more details so it can be re-opened (or you can even post new question clearly showing how to *reproduce* the problem - saying "does not work" is just not enough).